# RV320 router between 2 access points and secondary VLAN

Tags: cisco, lan, wan, bridge

I have a [Cisco RV320](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/routers/rv320-dual-gigabit-wan-vpn-router/index.html) that is sitting between 2 different routers/access points on my network. Essentially:

```
My ISP's router/access point <-----> RV320 <-----> My other access point
```

My setup is:

```
 - ISP's router (HomeHub 3000)
   - IP: 192.168.2.1
   - Subnet: 192.168.2.0/24
   - DHCP enabled

 - Cisco RV320
   - WAN1/WAN2 configured to obtain IP automatically, but no cable connected
   - LAN1 connected to my ISP router
   - LAN2 connected to my other access point
   - LAN3 connected to my home server
   - VLAN1
     - IP Address: 192.168.2.2, mask /24, DHCP disabled
     - untagged on all ports
   - VLAN10
     - IP Address: 192.168.10.1, mask /24, DHCP enabled 
     - tagged on LAN3

 - Other access point (Apple TimeCapsule)
   - IP: 192.168.2.64, mask /24, default gateway: 192.168.2.1
   - Routing mode: Off (Bridge Mode)
```

I want clients connected to each access point to be able to talk to each other. For that, I ended up connecting each access point to a LAN port on my RV320 (LAN1 & LAN2). They are considered to be the same network, so it traffic works.

The problem with that solution is that RV320 is not aware on how to communicate with the Internet, since it has nothing connected on the WAN port (and the WAN configuration is the only place I can specify a default gateway). And because of that, when my home server on LAN3 using VLAN10 tries to communicate out to the Internet, RV320 doesn't know where to send traffic to and just drops it.

Some ideas I had but wasn't able to find how/if I can do, or even if they would solve:

1. allow communication from WAN to LAN on the default VLAN; or
2. configure VLAN1 as bridge and VLAN10 as routing; or
3. configure a default gateway per VLAN, so that I could tell RV320 to send traffic from my special VLAN to my ISP's router.

Is there any way to achieve this setup with a RV320? 
Other suggestions are welcomed! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about home networking are explicitly off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [su].

Answer (score 1):

1. the ISP router needs to have a route to the 192.168.10.0/24 subnet via the RV320.
2. The RV320 needs a default route via the ISP router.
3. You need firewall rules in the RV320 permitting or denying communication between the VLANs and to/from the Internet. Note that as long as the ISP router is inside your LAN, your clients can just as well use that router.

A better setup would be to connect the ISP router to the RV320's WAN port, so that clients cannot use it directly. The additional LAN subnet would also require a route entry on the ISP router, of course. If you cannot configure routes on the ISP router you need to (double) source NAT on the RV320.

You cannot configure a VLAN as routed or bridged. A VLAN is a closed L2 segment/broadcast domain (all nodes are bridged together). A *VLAN interface* (SVI) is where you can route into or out of a VLAN.